# How to mock the line Integer.Parseint(authenticationmap.get("userid");

Tags: java, jmockit

How can i mock this code in jmockit
class A{
private Map authenticationMap;
.
.
.
public boolean createFirstTimerProfile(String password, String userName, String securityAnswer, String securityQuestion){

```
    String encryptedNewPassword = null;
    int userId;
    try {
        if(Util.isEmpty(password)||Util.isEmpty(userName)||Util.isEmpty(securityAnswer)||Util.isEmpty(securityQuestion))
            throw new CustomerEntryExceptions("values are null or empty");

        encryptedNewPassword =  encryptPassword(password);

        userId =(Integer.parseInt(authenticationMap.get("userid")));
        Connection con = Util.getConnection();
        if(clientUserManagement.addorupdatesecurityquestion(userName,securityQuestion, securityAnswer,userId,con)){
            String updatestatus = updateUserPassword(userId, encryptedNewPassword,
                     Boolean.parseBoolean(ServiceLocator.getConfigValue("authentication.fail_pwdchange_ind")),Integer.parseInt(ServiceLocator.getConfigValue("authentication.pwd_reason_firstlogin")));
            if(updatestatus.equals("updated")){
                velocityContextMembers = new HashMap<String,String>();
                velocityContextMembers.clear();
                velocityContextMembers.put("name", userName);
                velocityContextMembers.put("securityquestion", securityQuestion);
                velocityContextMembers.put("securityanswer", securityAnswer);
                velocityContextMembers.put("password", password);
                mailToUser(userId,"Authetication Profile Information","authenticationProfile_email_html.vm");
                return true;
            } else{
                throw new CustomerEntryExceptions("Password not updated");
            }
        } else{
            throw new CustomerEntryExceptions("Authentication profile not updated");
        }
    } catch (CustomerEntryExceptions e) {
        logger.error("createFirstTimerProfile() --> "+e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }

}
```

}

How to mock the line Integer.Parseint(authenticationmap.get("userid");

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to mock it. I believe it would be far easier to simply put the userid in the map and let the code run from there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm agree with  jan.vdbergh, i'm not sure mocking is the best solution.

But if you want to mock a static methodcan  procced like this:

```
@Test
public void myTestMethod(){
      new Expectations(){
          @Mocked 
          Integer integer= null;

          {
               Integer.parseInt(anyString);
               result = new NumberFormatException();

          }

       }
}
```